# Link to CSS without /index.php/ in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have CodeIgniter without /index.php/ URL and i want to link CSS file in views.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^([a-zA-z0-9/])
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt|system|user_guide)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/metrohacker/style.css" />
```

With /index.php/ it works, but i want simple URL...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because your application folder isn't in the list of folders that aren't rewritten in your htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt|system|user_guide)
```

I would keep your CSS files in the root of the app rather than in the views folder.  I would do the same with your JavaScripts and images too.  That way your folder structure would be something like:

```
root/
    application/
    assets/
        css/
        js/
        images/
    system/
...
```

Make sure to add the **assets** folder to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt|system|user_guide|assets)
```

Then you don't have to worry about index.php doing the routing and you can just load a CSS file like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css" />
```